# How to generate reports for Azure Log Activity Data using python for any resource alongwith 'Tags'?

Tags: azure, reporting-services, terraform, azure-resource-manager, azure-rest-api

My colleague used the below powershell query to retrieve log data for past 4 days excluding today which matches operations of the resources and collects features such as EventTimeStamp, Caller, SubscriptionId etc.

```
Get-AzureRmLog -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-4) -EndTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | Where-Object {$_.OperationName.LocalizedValue -match "Start|Stop|Restart|Create|Update|Delete"} |
Select-Object EventTimeStamp, Caller, SubscriptionId, @{name="Operation"; Expression = {$_.operationname.LocalizedValue}},
```

I am a newbie to azure and want to generate a report where I can also fetch the 'Tags' name & value against a resource for past 90 days in this report. What will be the powershell query for this? Can I also use python to query this data? I tried searching the documentation and was unable to dig into it, so if anybody could redirect me to the right place it will be helpful.

Comment: Regarding "I can also fetch the 'Tags' name & value", can you elaborate it? you want to also get the resource tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should know that not all azure resources can specify tags, so you should consider this in your code. Please refer to [Tag support for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-support) to check which azure resource supports tags.

For powershell query, I suggest using the [new azure powershell az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.8.0) instead of the old [azureRM module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.13.0).

Here is a simple powershell code with **az module**. And for testing purpose, I just introduce how to fetch and add tags to the output. Please feel free to change it as per your requirement.

```
#for testing purpose, I just get the azure activity logs from a specified resource group
$mylogs = Get-AzLog -ResourceGroupName "a resource group name"

foreach($log in $mylogs)
{   

    if(($log.Properties.Content.Values -ne $null))
    {
        #the tags is contains in the Properties of the log entry.
        $s = $log.Properties.Content.Values -as [string]
        if($s.startswith("{"))
        {
            $log | Select-Object EventTimeStamp, Caller, SubscriptionId,@{name="Operation"; Expression = {$_.operationname.LocalizedValue}}, @{name="tags"; Expression = {($s | ConvertFrom-Json).tags}}      
        }
        #if it does not contains tags.
        else
        {
            $log | Select-Object EventTimeStamp, Caller, SubscriptionId,@{name="Operation"; Expression = {$_.operationname.LocalizedValue}}, @{name="tags"; Expression = {""}}
        }
    }
    #if it does not contains tags.
    else
    {
        $log | Select-Object EventTimeStamp, Caller, SubscriptionId,@{name="Operation"; Expression = {$_.operationname.LocalizedValue}}, @{name="tags"; Expression = {""}}
    }

    Write-Output "************************"
}
```

The test result:

[image]

For python, you can take a look at [this github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/4372) which introduces how to fetch logs from azure activity logs, but you need do some research on how to add tags to the output.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem.is it a good practice to use KQL(Kusto query language) for querying log data?

Comment: @ShreyasMoolya, yes, KQL is a good practice used to query log data, and it's very powerful(many built-in functions; it can generate charts; it can also cross-query from azure monitor / azure log analytics etc.)

Comment: Does KQL requires a azure-data-explorer/ database created to query the data?

Comment: @ShreyasMoolya, no, if you want to use KQL, just write your query in azure log analytics.